# A block disappeared on my site, how do I bring it back?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-views

I own a thedollies.com.au, a website selling greeting cards. I had programmers help me build the site.
On the homepage, there were 4 categories: Testimonials, Latest News, Discussions and DailyBread. One day, the DailyBread category disappeared. 
Please help me bring it back.

I found that the portion for this DailyBread category is named aggregator-block_1. 
I searched my site's script for aggregator-block_1 and found a few locations:

1) The first is in a file named utilities.js. The content:

```
Drupal.utilities = {};
Drupal.behaviors.utilities = function() {
 $("#block-views-aggregator-block_1 .view-aggregator a").attr("target","_blank");
 $("#block-views-aggregator-block_1 .view-aggregator .dailynews-more a").removeAttr("target");
}
```

2) I also found it in a file named dollies.css, which I believe is my site's main css file:

```
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_1,#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_2{
    float:left;
    width:230px;

}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_3,#block-views-aggregator-block_1{

    float:left;
    width:230px;
}
.view-dollies-blog-view,.view-id-aggregator{
padding:5px 0 0 25px;
}
.view-dollies-blog-view a,#block-views-aggregator-block_1 a{
padding-left:8px;
margin-top:-5px;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_3 a{
background:url(../images/news_b.png) no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
color:#7f3c9b;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_1 a{
background:url(../images/test_b.png) no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
color:#1e6fc9;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_2 a{
background:url(../images/dis_b.png) no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
color:#fa4365;
}
#block-views-aggregator-block_1 a{
background:url(../images/bread_b.png) no-repeat;
background-position:left center;
color:#24946e;
}
#block-views-aggregator-block_1  h2.title{
height:30px;
background:url(../images/bread.png) no-repeat;
text-indent:-999em;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_3 h2.title{
    height:35px;
    background:url(../images/news.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-999em;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_1 h2.title{
    height:35px;
    background:url(../images/testimonials.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-999em;
}
#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_2 h2.title{
    height:30px;
    background:url(../images/discussion.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-999em;
}

#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_3 .news-more a,#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_1 .more a,#block-views-aggregator-block_1 .dailynews-more a,#block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_2 .discussion-more a{
background:none;
}
```

I'm not sure what I should change to bring the DailyBread category back to the homepage.
Or is there something wrong with a MySQL entry? I didn't do anything and this category just suddenly disappeared.

Comment: Sure you're not looking for `block-views-dollies_blog_view-block_4`? Because, given the number scheme, that seems to make more sense. And seems like it would belong in the `div#content-bottom` block. (As an aside, you don't appear to have any dormant code in the HTML (there but just hidden) so I'm thinking it's a Server-side fubar.)

Comment: It's not any of that code, and I'm afraid we can't easily guess what other code there is... don't you have backups of the code and database from before it changing?

Comment: I just checked your site and it seems the HTML isn't even being loaded into the page...

Comment: Since it disappeared after a certain time, I imagine the content had a date to expire on (it is "daily" after all), at which point you were supposed to update the content to be displayed there? It's unclear - you should really contact your programmers and ask them how the content is set, as it is unlikely that this is either a javascript or CSS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to get into views for this one.

1. Login and take a little trip over to http://YOURSITE/admin/build/views
2. look for this "aggregator" view and
   click the "export" link
3. Select the entire view text and copy it, then paste it into a new pastie over at http://www.pastie.org/ and link to it so we can see what taxonomy terms, content types etc this view is looking for, then we'll have some info to be able to help you :)

Edit: Now that we know what is in the view:

The view depends on the Feeds Aggregator, to manage Aggregator Items go to:

http://YOURSITE/admin/content/aggregator/list

The view creates a block called Aggregator, To manage blocks go to:

http://YOURSITE/admin/build/block

Cheers

Comment: @jpstrikesback thanks for your help. I encountered another amateur problem.. tried googling for answers but can't find one that helps. How do you login actually? I tried logging into the cpanel but I can't access http://thedollies.com.au/admin/build/views. It says 'Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.' Sorry for my amateurishness T_T

Comment: No worries! glad to be able to help :) go to http://YOURSITE/user and then just enter your Drupal user/pass, if you cannot get in, you should be able to send a pw reset email to yourself (as long as the email on file for the admin user is you). If you can't get in that way, there are still ways.

Comment: @jpstrikesback woah that's cool I didn't know you can have an admin portal like that! anyways I did what you told me and here's the link. http://www.pastie.org/1566341. Thank you

Comment: OK from that code I would say you need to go look at the feeds your are aggregating and also check the Aggregator Block to make sure it is enabled. I'll edit my answer to indicate where to look, you'll need to read up on how to use the Feed Aggregator & Block Admin

Comment: @jpstrikesback Thank you so much! it's fixed! you're awesome thanks! If you have time, please have a look at http://bit.ly/gVfZVG too. I'm trying to fix the paypal link on the checkout page. Again, thanks! vote for u.

Comment: Apparently I can't do that yet.. T_T

Comment: glad to help, see my answer on that question :)